# ipython: cannot import name download

Tags: python, import, pip, ipython

I installed the complete pattern package:

- pip install pattern

When I want to use `download`, I get the following message:

```
ImportError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-83512f2723dc> in <module>()
      6 
      7 from pattern.web import PDF
----> 8 from pattern.web import download, plaintext
      9 from textblob_de import TextBlobDE as TextBlob
     10 

ImportError: cannot import name download
```

Comment: Can you please copy the stacktrace of your error into a code block? Your question is very hard to read.

Comment: I edited you post and updated the tags. Tags determine what audience sees your question. Carefully choosing appropriate tags will increase chances to get a good answer.

Comment: That said: I do not see this issue here. Maybe `pip` and `ipython` point to two different python interpreters. You could try using `ipython -m pip -- install --upgrade pattern` and see if this fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Yeah, I didn´t know the "upgrade"-command, I said, Im a newbie ;) So, the problem is solved.

Comment: I hope, this will be noticed. Now, I have to use another computer, and after writing "pip --upgrade pattern" it says "no such option". I really dont get it.

Comment: Please feel free to post another question. Don't forget to include the full stack trace and as many details as possible.